# Protected content strings in JSON producing DD4T TBB(s)

Tags: dd4t, template-building-blocks

I think we've stumbled into an edge-case issue with the JSON producing DD4T TBB(s), so I am looking for some input / confirmation.

We have a Schema, which has a simple text-field and a multivalued embedded Schema. The embedded Schema is a standard "link" Schema - with an internal Component link, an external text field - etc.

**Component**

[image]

**Problem**

The problem we've run into is that if we include the string `ComponentTemplate` in a text-field, the Component Presentation is not included in the list of Component Presentations in the Page JSON. The string is not case-sensitive, so `componenttemplate` also excludes the Component Presentation from the rendered output.

When we run the Component Template against the Component in Template Builder, there is output which looks valid. There seems to be no issues there. The issue only seems to be adding the Component Presentation to the Page JSON.

*Note that the Component Template is **static**.*

**What we've tried**

- We've tried removing special characters (ampersands etc), which has no effect.
- We've also tried moving the string around - but again, no change.
- Tried the string in both embedded fields, & direct content fields. Same result.

**The following URLs exclude the Component Presentation from output:**

- http://dev.test-server.com?Component=123&ComponentTemplate=456
- http://dev.componenttemplate.com
- http://dev.test-server.com?ComponentTemplate

**The following URLs work fine:**

- http://dev.test-server.com?ComponentTemplat
- http://dev.component-template.com

I'm not quite sure what would cause this issue. It's a bit of a strange one that we just happened to notice by chance. We assumed it was the ampersand, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Josh, are there any errors/warning/info in the dd4t log? Try setting the log level to TRACE and see if something useful shows up in there. From the looks of it, I think it has to do something with JSON parsing and if there's bad JSON in there then I would expect the log files to indicate the same.

Comment: Hey Kunal. I've checked the logs & didn't see anything useful. I didn't see any errors or warnings indicating that the JSON parsing failed, even though I suspect you're right :)

Comment: Hi Josh, could you provide the generated JSON please?

Comment: Hi Josh, could you post the generated sample JSON?

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys @PhilMedcraft - here's the sample JSON https://pastebin.com/YNVHi7c5. The CP is on the page, but is left out of the JSON. If I remove that string from content, the CP comes back in the JSON.

Comment: Please see above comment @Velmurugan. I can only tag one person / comment.

Comment: DD4T is open-source. Have you considered compiling it yourself and debugging it?

Comment: @JoshHebb - Is that issue fixed? 
I did try to replicate this issue, but it's working fine for me.
https://pastebin.com/raw/MrU5n9t9, DD4T template version I did test 2.1.0 (DD4T.Templates.merged.dll)

Comment: Are you using the CT 'Generate Dynamic Component', @JoshHebb? If so, can you change to 'Generate Dynamic Component Presentation' and try again?